# Dynamic data validation based on joined reference data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having troubles finding a correct formula to validate data based on 'joined' reference data and actual data.

I have two reference data groups in a reference sheet:

| FRUIT_ID | FRUIT_NAME |  | BASKET_ID | BASKET_TYPE | FRUIT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |  | BAS-1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | Banana |  | BAS-1 | 10 | 2 |
| 3 | Pineapple |  | BAS-1 | 20 | 1 |
|  |  |  | BAS-2 | 10 | 2 |

The `FRUIT` references the available data. The `BASKET` references the available baskets, but there is a rule that says that only some fruits are allowed in each basket. The above table aims to specify:

- There are 3 fruits available for selection, identified by an ID
- There are 2 baskets available for selection, identified by a composite [ID, Type]
- Each basket has a restricted set of selectable fruits

  - [BAS-1, 10] can select Apple and Banana
  - [BAS-1, 20] can select Apple
  - [BAS-2, 10] can select Banana

I then have data in another sheet where users should be able to interact, and I want the data validation to present - via drop-down - only the values that are allowed in the context. For example:

| ROW | BASKET_ID | BASKET_TYPE | FRUIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BAS-1 | 10 | X |
| 2 | BAS-1 | 20 | X |
| 3 | BAS-2 | 10 | X |

My goal is to have a drop-down in the `FRUIT` column that only allows row_1 to select Banana and Apple, row_2 to select Apple, row_3 to select Banana.
I have not found a way to join the data to display the actual fruit name. The closest I got so far is with this formula:

```
=OFFSET(FRUIT; MATCH(BASKET_ID; REFS_BASKET_ID ; 0) - 1; 0; COUNTIF(REFS_BASKET_ID; BASKET_ID); 1)
```

But that formula isn't enough because:

- It doesn't take into account the basket type, because only the pair ID/TYPE is unique.
- It displays the `FRUIT_ID` while I need the `FRUIT_TYPE`

How can I achieve this? The template is not a strong requirement.

Comment: Regarding Row 1: Does the user have to select "Banana and apple" or might she select "Banana" or "Apple" or "Banana and Apple"? Because for the last case you would need more "Fruit"-columns in your third table ...

Comment: @Ike It's a single selection, user select one value from the drop-down containing the allowed ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a tough one. Maybe I'm not aware of better options, but what I did was that I created a spilled dynamic array first on your reference-tab. This data I then referenced as a custom list data validation. It would look something like:

[image]

Formula in `N2`:

```
=IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(0,I2:I4,LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,LET(z,TOROW(FILTER(F2:F5,(D2:D5=INDEX(J2:J4,y))*(E2:E5=INDEX(K2:K4,y)))),FILTER(B2:B4,MMULT(N(A2:A4=z),SEQUENCE(COUNT(z),,,0))))))),,1),"")
```

I then selected `L2:L4` and added the custom reference:

[image]

Now, we can select each of those cells and it will have it's own custom drop-down list:

[image]

I tried to leave the errors alone in the spilled array at first and tried to use `TOCOL()` in the source, however that would not be allowed it seems by Excel. Hence you will be left with some empty-string values.

Hopefully someone else has a more straightforward solution for you to work with =)

---

**EDIT:**

Same thing, larger input lists:

[image]

Comment: Wow,I thought about using a named lambda something like `=LAMBDA(x,y,XLOOKUP(FILTER(E2:E5,(C2:C5=x)*(D2:D5=y)),A2:A4,B2:B4))(@J:J,@K:K)` but when naming it it works in the cell, but referencing the name in the drop-down won't work. This is a nice formula solution, but I think to get a real clean solution, we need VBA. Maybe we can sort the indexed values, to have the blanks appear on the bottom?

Comment: To bad ARRAYTOTEXT isn't compatible to dropdown

Comment: `=INDEX($N$2#,row($A$1:index($A:$A,SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(INDEX($N$2#,,@I:I))>0)))),@I:I)` also fails when referring to that.

Comment: @P.b VBA would also be okay in this instance. It would be better without it, but if that's the only way, I can live with it

Comment: @JvdV, thanks that's a really nice answer! After trying your sample, I tried it out on the actual data, but this spilled array doesn't generate when the ranges are greater than the data, which seems to make the sheet very limited to a pre-defined set of data, or perhaps my adaptions were incorrect. I tried both with an `INDIRECT` range and by putting large ranges. But it seems that regardless, the spilled table is probably not adequate for the data which can have thousands of different 'fruits' and 'baskets'

Comment: @Dranna, it really should work on larger ranges if applied correctly. I'm no longer behind a pc though for further testing. Please make sure you adjust the ranges properly.

Comment: Regardless it not being the clean end result, it's a very useful and creative answer. I tagged vba for a different approach

Comment: @p.b, just found out that there would simply be just one empty string (see latest GIF, when I click ROW 5). The data validation list seems to auto-remove if more than 1. Very pleased with the answer now then!

Comment: Agreed. Superb!

Comment: Thank you both, I'm going to accept this as an answer because it works, but it also highlights that the design of the sheet is not sustainable. If I'm not mistaken, this will have a hard limit by the amount of columns for the spill table, apparently currently 16.384, and the data currently can be two or three times that amount.